# printing a "for i in range" command

Tags: python, sql, printing, sqlite

I have a list of entries in the entry.get() and so each time it is called it outputs the next data piece for the sql code to use. I need it to output all the data in the entry and so I wanted to do this by using a `for I in range` except with my relevant words. Is this possible?

```
print(sql,for entry in entries:
    (entry.get())
```

Effectively, I want it to print the line of SQL code followed by the data in entry.get(). Thanks

Edit:

The type of data in entry.get() might produce
"ProductID, ProductName, ProductDescription", for example "1,Chocolate,Yummy"

Comment: Can you post the code in the `.get()` method that you're calling if it's something that you've written yourself?

Comment: Look up comprehensions for abbreviated syntax like this - you can't put a colon in line like that.

Comment: Sure, Ill edit my question to include this.

Comment: sentences like "outputs the next data piece for the sql code to use" literally makes no sense and should be clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all we are dealing with here are strings then either of the two following methods will get you there.

Using a standard python for each loop, your code would look something like this:

```
for entry in entries:
     print sql + entry
```

Using a list comprehension you can do this all in one line like this:

```
print [sql + entry for entry in entries]
```

However, if you intend to call entry.get(), you must make sure that "entries" is an iterable full of objects that contain the method get(). Then:

```
for entry in entries:
    print sql + entry.get()
```

If you really want to use the `i in range()` syntax then it might look like this:

```
for i in range(len(entries)):
     print sql + entries[i].get()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `print(sql, '\n'.join(entry.get() for entry in entries))`.